Stencil doesn't export types in React Typescript app
I have created a Stencil app and consumed it with React and Typescript. It all works as expected apart from the component type declarations. Stencil does create the types in dist/types on build but they are not correctly interpret in my React app by Typescript. When I try to use one of the stencil components I get error:
Property 'my-comp' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.ts(2339)
My package.json has types exported like this:
"types": "dist/types/index.d.ts",
"exports": {
  ".": {
    "import": "./dist/my-components/my-components.esm.js"
  },
  "./my-component": {
    "import": "./dist/components/my-component.js",
    "types": "./dist/components/my-component.d.ts"
  },
  "./loader": {
    "import": "./loader/index.js",
    "types": "./loader/index.d.ts"
  },
  "./styles": "./dist/my-components/my-components.css"
},

I outputTargets are:
   outputTargets: [
    {
      type: "dist",
      esmLoaderPath: "../loader",
    },
    {
      type: "dist-custom-elements",
      customElementsExportBehavior: "auto-define-custom-elements",
      externalRuntime: false,
    },
    {
      type: "docs-readme",
    },
    {
      type: "www",
      serviceWorker: null,
    },
  ],

Is there a way to import the component types automatically from the build without using the React Integration?
I can make it work if I add a components.d.ts file in my src folder in my React app and declare the types there but want to automate it somehow without using @lit/react.
My components.d.ts file has this structure when I create it manually:
 type IMyComp = {
   name: string;
   size: string;
 }
 declare namespace JSX {
   interface IntrinsicElements {
     'my-comp': IMyComp;
   }
 }

I tried to use the auto-generated one from dist/types/index.d.ts or components.d.ts but neither works.
Adding this actually works:
import { Components as MyComponents } from '@myStencilComps/ui/dist';

 declare global {
   namespace JSX {
     export interface IntrinsicElements {
       'my-comp': MyComponents.MyComp;
     }
   }
 }

But the next problem I face is error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/@fs/Users/../../../ui/dist/my-components/my-components.esm.js' does not provide an export named 'Size' (at App.tsx:8:10)
when I try to use
<my-comp
  name="myTest"
  size={Size.Md}
/>

where size is an enum type declared in types folder in my stencil project
export enum Size {
  SM = 'sm',
  MD = 'md',
  LG = 'lg',
}

export default Rounded;


